# VIA connection pins

Tags: pcb, connector, via

Is there any similar alternatives to this [via pins](https://www.harwin.com/products/T1558-01/) ? Is there a general name for this kind of connector that I can google on?
Or probably there is a tool for producing this kind of tapered pins from a regular wire?

[image: Via pins]

Comment: Instead of trying to make vias yourself, I think many people today are preferring to just let a company like [OSHPark](https://oshpark.com/) handle their hobbyist-level designs, or a more professional firm for prototype boards/assembly. OSHPark produces VERY nice boards for little money.

Comment: @rdtsc: Yes, but does it ship to Minsk, Belarus for a reasonable sum?

Comment: [Sure](http://support.oshpark.com/support/solutions/articles/123330-shipping-information-and-turnaround-times), and basic shipping is free but can take anywhere from 3 days to 3 weeks.

Comment: The cheapest I've found is $25 for a 5x5 board and I need 10x15 for my project and these are probably no less than a $100. If I was doing this professionally this would make sense but for a hobby project it's a lot of money for a board here.

Comment: You could also buy a two-sided generic (10x16 cm) project board with vias made... e.g. http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1909608.pdf (this is a high-quality one). Perhaps you can find cheaper, made-in-China ones somewhere.

Comment: Itead are $50 for 10 at 10cm x 15cm.

Comment: Here, this site will compare all the cheap prototype houses and give you shipping time to your country: http://pcbshopper.com

Comment: Since you are in Belarus you might want to evaluate Olimex in Bulgaria rather than a US supplier.  For just improvising vias on "need it today" handmand boards I tend to  use 30-guage wire, fold it along the tracks and solder it there as it turns out that getting a good fillet around a non-plated hole on *both* sides of a PCB can be challenging given the tendency of trapped gas to displace the solder.

Comment: What I ended up doing is just putting straight pieces of wire (any solid core wire thin enough for the holes should do) through the holes and soldering them on both sides. First putting the board across 2 books with a gap in between then filling the holes with pieces of wire the space under the board  allowing the wires to stand, soldering the upper side, cutting the excess wire on the upper side, turning it over and soldering the lower side and cutting the excess on the lower side. Doing it this way appears to be quite productive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the attraction of getting boards done fairly cheaply, I still like to do things on stripboard and these "via pins" still have a use. Harwin don't do them any more, but Vero in the UK still do a lot of different pins at reasonable prices and have stock of most on 07 Nov 2015.

One of the uses I put them to, is mounting SMD's on the non-track side of a single sided board - very useful for things like PSU sockets that are sometimes only available in SMD form.

Answer (score 1):

These are known as via or pcb ***Rivets***. Some are hollow tubes, others are solid wire, and some are shaped. You can find them in a variety of finishes.

You probably won't find a tool to make cone shaped tapered ones like you pictured, but you can make simple ones with some wire and hammer. See:  https://paulwanamaker.wordpress.com/300-2/ Standard riveting method applies here as it would armor or metal fabricated PC enclosures.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this but if you put wire in a vice so that the tip of the wire pokes up about 1mm and then hit it with a hammer the top should flatten. Then just cut and repeat.

If you try this let me know how it works.